# Monodroid - Cant start new Activity/Intent

Tags: c#, android, android-activity, mono, xamarin.android

I am making an app using monodroid and i am trying to start a new activity.

Below is my code i am using to start the new activity

```
var second = new Intent(this, typeof(CreateVehicle));
        StartActivity(second);
```

and this is the Create Vehicle Activity

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;

namespace BoostITAndroid.Android
{
[Activity(Label = "My Activity")]
public class CreateVehicle : Activity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        // Create your application here
    }
}
}
```

My problem is I cant run the application because in the intent CreateVehicle is under lined red and it says it doesnt exist.

Comment: Tried cleaning the project and try again? What if you create another `Activity` and try with that?

Answer (score 0):

add

```
<activity 
        android:name="YourPackageName.SecondActivityNameOnly"
        />
```

to you **AndroidManifest.xml**

it should look like this :

```
     <activity
     android:name="com.webview.MainActivity"
     android:label="@string/app_name" >
     <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity 
    android:name="YourPackageName.SecondActivityNameOnly"
    />
```

Comment: I tried declaring it in my manifest and then I got an error saying I dont have a main class. Do you have an example I could see?

Comment: i think you are trying to renaming MainActivity inside AndroidManifest.xml ? if so dont do that just add new activity tag i gonna show you the example !

Comment: also the .class didnt work. You know this is C# right? (mondroid)

Comment: This is not the way to do it in Xamarin.Android. The manifest gets generated on compile time.

Answer (score 0):

What I've found when problems arise with manifest just doing a simple clean of the project fixes the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I see two possible issues:
1. The CreateVehicle activity is missing SetContentView method;
2. May be you have CreateVehicle activity in another namespace